# Default cell type in OOXML spreadsheet

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi, openxml, libreoffice-calc

I've received weird XLSX file (OOXML). Here is some code fragment of its sheet (xl/worksheets/sheet1.xml):

```
    <row r="2" spans="1:6" x14ac:dyDescent="0.25">
        <c r="A2" s="11" t="s">
            <v>33</v>
        </c>
        <c r="B2" s="10">
            <v>444</v>
        </c>
        <c r="C2" s="5"/>
        <c r="D2" s="12">
            <v>1</v>
        </c>
        <c r="E2" s="5"/>
        <c r="F2" s="3"/>
    </row>
```

Note the second cell - it has no 't' attribute.
According to [ECMA-376](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-376.htm) (Annex A.2, page 3918, line 2301), the default type for cell (if it is not mentioned) is 'n' (Number):

```
<xsd:attribute name="t" type="ST_CellType" use="optional" default="n"/>
```

If I try to call [getCellType()](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/4.1/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Cell.html#getCellType--) in [Apache POI](https://poi.apache.org/), I get `NUMERIC`. That's is OK.

But when I open the file with LibreOffice, I see that the cell has 'Text' type:
[image]
Is there any explanations to this ?

PS. The file is produced by MS Excel

Comment: Cell types and formats are different things in Excel!

Comment: @Gagravarr Do you mean that getCellType() != Category (at the picture)?

Comment: Cell Type is about the storage in the file format, plus a bunch of stuff around what can/can't be done. Cell Data Formats are about how raw numbers in the file get formatted into numbers / dates / % / currencies / etc

Comment: According to your showed `XML`: In `<c r="B2" s="10">` the attribute `s` (Style Index) points to a cell style in the styles part which number format is set to `@` (Text). That means the cell is formatted using number format Text. This has nothing to do with attribute `t` (Cell Data Type).

Comment: @AxelRichter thank you for the answer, it was a discovery for me that string can be stored in numeric format

Answer (score 0):

I managed with the issue (thanks to @AxelRichter comment).

The main thing is that a **string can be stored at `NUMERIC` type cell**. For this purpose, special `@` format is used.

Here is code (Apache POI):

```
String fs = c.getCellStyle().getDataFormatString();
if (BuiltinFormats.getBuiltinFormat(fs)==49){
    String value = ((XSSFCell)c).getRawValue();
    //do something
}
```

[Link to BuiltinFormats](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/4.1/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/BuiltinFormats.html)